# Mac OSX: How to restore Chrome to default settings after having run it in the terminal once

Tags: google-chrome, terminal

I ran the following command:

`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222`

so that I could debug an application I'm developing; however, now whenever I try to open up Chrome by searching it with `Cmd+Space` it opens a Chrome process where my tabs are not restored and I'm not signed into Chrome anymore. The only way to get Chrome to run correctly is to run the command above without the `--remote-debugging-port` argument.

Is there any way to fix this? I don't want to have to use the terminal every time I need to open Chrome.

EDIT: Also just noticed that clicking on a link in my email opens up another Google Chrome process rather than defaulting to the one already running, which is definitely not optimal behavior.